# How can use some session for multiple browser tabs in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, session, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, session-variables

I want go to profile each students then execute some action for each use like (Edit, add class, ...).

Got this URL `/students/profile/1` for profile of student.

I want to go to profiles for 3 students:

- Student 1 `/students/profile/1`
- Student 2 `/students/profile/2`
- Student 3 `/students/profile/3`

`Profile` action method:

```
public IActionResult Profile(long? id)
{
    HttpContext.Session.SetInt32(".ProfileStudent.StudentId", id); // set session

    return View();
}
```

If I need data for student for a given Id in session id:

```
URL => /students/profile/1

public IActionResult EditInfo()
{
    var id = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32(".ProfileStudent.StudentId");

    var student = db.Student.Find(id);
    return View(student );
}

URL => /students/profile/2

public IActionResult EditInfo()
{
    var id = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32(".ProfileStudent.StudentId");

    var student = db.Student.Find(id);
    return View(student );
}
```

Now data conflicted and return last value session.

How to get data session for each user per browser tab?

Comment: session is per user. not for tab. why you don't use parameter?

Comment: My example simple only for explain, Need  session  per tab

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advice against storing and using parameters this way for multiple reasons and opening multiple tabs will not solve your problem anyways. Just pass through the specific id as a parameter to the `EditInfo` method, that way you can use multiple tabs at the same time.

```
public IActionResult EditInfo(int id)
{
    var student = db.Student.Find(id);
    return View(student );
}
```

Comment: My example simple only for explain, Need session per tab you can see like Facebook group include some action and not merged each tab